# Setting working directory in PyCham doesn't seem to work

Tags: python, flask, pycharm

I keep running into path issues in my flask app, when running in PyCharm. I've set the working directory in my run configuration to `project-root/api/src`, but the relative paths to resources don't resolve properly.

To check what's going on I ran `os.getcwd()` and I'm getting `project-root`.

What am I doing wrong? I tested the same project with a colleague with a identical (to my knowledge) configuration and on his machine `os.getcwd()` properly returns what is expected,  `project-root/api/src`.

I tried reconfiguring the project from scratch, by removing `.idea` folder and creating the project again in PyCharm, to no avail.

I'm using macOs BigSur, Python 3.9 and PyCharm 2021.2.1.
Screenshot below contains my configuration (sensitive info, like company/project name removed):

[image: configuration and debug console output]

Comment: well I had a similar problem in a dash app (dash is base on flask)
in the end the solution was that when running flask automatically add a sub folder name assets and was looking there and as I did not created this folder and the files where in the base folder I got similar exception

Comment: For anyone wondering how I resolved my issue - I've removed the folder completely (not just the *.idea folder), downloaded the project from git and set it up again. The problem stopped appearing.

Must've been some leftover pycharm configuration files which I missed.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this issue myself - the reason was that I'm using pipenv, which requires a `.env` file to be present in the root of the project folder. Flask, when finding such a file, switches the working directory to the root project folder, disregarding any PyCharm setting.

A solution to this is to add a `FLASK_SKIP_DOTENV=1` to the application environment variables.

Described in detail here: https://github.com/pallets/flask/issues/3209